# jQuery show/hide content based on length, issue with multiple inner html tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to adopt this code for my purposes: https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Show-Hide-Long-Text-Max-Length-jQuery.html

My working Fiddle is located here: https://jsfiddle.net/bsummers/zo5gpnvj/3/

---

My issue is that the content (from WordPress) has tags within it like p & ul, and when those come into play the script breaks.

If I change the following:

`var content = $(this).html();`
to
`var content = $(this).text();`

The show/hide seems to work, but then it strips all the HTML. I'd like to retain the paragraph spacing and any lists inside, I assume it's possible somehow but I'm stuck on how to get that to work.

Any direction is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you would sometimes need to cut the text in the middle of a tag. I understand having only the text is ox for the brief/preview, but when you show all you suddenly need the whole markup again.

The solution would be to do both, get a simple `.text()` for the preview and the whole `.html()` for the detailed view, but then the transition isn't going to be as smooth.

Does this work for you?

```js
/*------------ Show / Hide Text ------------*/
function showHideText(sSelector, options) {
    // Def. options
    var defaults = {
        charQty     : 100,
        ellipseText : "...",
        moreText    : "Show more",
        lessText    : "Show less"
    };

    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    var s = this;

        s.container = $(sSelector);
        s.containerH = s.container.height();

        s.container.each(function() {
            var content = $(this).text();
            var htmlContent = $(this).html();

            if(content.length > settings.charQty) {

                var visibleText = content.substr(0, settings.charQty);
                var hiddenText  = htmlContent;

                var html = '<span class="previewText">' + visibleText + '</span>'
                         + '<span class="moreellipses">' +
                           settings.ellipseText
                         + '</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' +
                           hiddenText
                         + '</span><a href="" class="morelink">' +
                           settings.moreText
                         + '</a></span>';

                $(this).html(html);
            }

        });

        s.showHide = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(settings.moreText);

                $(this).prev().slideToggle('fast', function() {
                    $(this).parent().prev().slideToggle('fast');
                });
                
                $(this).closest(sSelector).find(".previewText").slideToggle('fast');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(settings.lessText);

                $(this).parent().prev().slideToggle('fast');
                $(this).prev().slideToggle('fast');
                
                $(this).closest(sSelector).find(".previewText").slideToggle('fast');
            }
        }

        $(".morelink").bind('click', s.showHide);
}
/*------------------------------------------*/

new showHideText('.myContent', {
    charQty     : 250,
    ellipseText : "...",
    moreText    : "Show",
    lessText    : "Hide"
});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}
.morelink {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.morelink:after {
  content: '';
  -ms-flex-item-align: start;
  align-self: flex-start;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
.morelink.less:after {
  margin-left: 7px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.previewText, .morecontent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
Works with no other HTML tags in the content
</h3>
<div class="myContent">
Duis hendrerit orci lorem, non rutrum sem imperdiet non. Quisque gravida mi vel sem egestas, a condimentum magna molestie. Integer a tellus malesuada, posuere turpis vitae, tincidunt est. Maecenas accumsan maximus magna ac vestibulum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc vel purus lacinia ipsum aliquam placerat eleifend at dolor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nisl risus, consectetur non ultricies eu, venenatis ac libero. Curabitur sem lectus, aliquet eget bibendum non, dignissim vitae quam. Sed in euismod est. Quisque vitae dolor eget turpis accumsan varius. Maecenas malesuada lectus vel turpis rhoncus, posuere ornare magna lobortis. Morbi eget orci ut ligula bibendum cursus. Donec eu rhoncus urna. Curabitur pulvinar lacus at ante cursus, sed lacinia dolor pulvinar.
</div>

<hr/>

<h3>
Doesn't work with other HTML tags in the content like p tags
</h3>
<div class="myContent">
<p>
Duis hendrerit orci lorem, non rutrum sem imperdiet non. Quisque gravida mi vel sem egestas, a condimentum magna molestie. Integer a tellus malesuada, posuere turpis vitae, tincidunt est. Maecenas accumsan maximus magna ac vestibulum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc vel purus lacinia ipsum aliquam placerat eleifend at dolor.
</p> 
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nisl risus, consectetur non ultricies eu, venenatis ac libero. Curabitur sem lectus, aliquet eget bibendum non, dignissim vitae quam. Sed in euismod est. Quisque vitae dolor eget turpis accumsan varius. Maecenas malesuada lectus vel turpis rhoncus, posuere ornare magna lobortis. Morbi eget orci ut ligula bibendum cursus. Donec eu rhoncus urna. Curabitur pulvinar lacus at ante cursus, sed lacinia dolor pulvinar.</p>
</div>

<hr/>

<h3>
Doesn't work with other HTML tags in the content like ul tags
</h3>
<div class="myContent">
<p>
Duis hendrerit orci lorem, non rutrum sem imperdiet non. Quisque gravida mi vel sem egestas, a condimentum magna molestie. Integer a tellus malesuada, posuere turpis vitae, tincidunt est. Maecenas accumsan maximus magna ac vestibulum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc vel purus lacinia ipsum aliquam placerat eleifend at dolor.
</p> 
<ul>
  <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</li>
  <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</li>
  <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</li>
</ul>
</div>

<br/><br/>
```

Comment: Wow, Wow, Wow!! Using both .html() and .text() seems so simple I feel dumb now. Thank you so much, this totally works. I only altered it a little to remove the transitions. Works like a charm :) https://jsfiddle.net/bsummers/e826ur1a/5/